# Print out the distribution of words in multiple files

Tags: shell

I am trying to make an executable that will take in any number of text files and give an output that is the distribution of words by number of occurrences. This is to be done in bash scripting, and what I have so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash
y=$(cat $* | wc -w)

cat $* | tr ' ' '//' |  tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' | tr -d '[:punct:]' | 
grep -v '[^a-z]'| sort | uniq -c | sort -rn | head -$y
```

I get an error trying to set `y` and I can't figure out how to get `head` to print out every word otherwise.

Is there a better way to print it out?

Comment: That is a good use of `cat` (both times) — no UUOC Award for you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why run `head` at all?  There's no guarantee that there will be as many words as there are words in the files; indeed, it is practically guaranteed that there won't be (since there'll be some repeated words).  And if you want to see all the data, then show all the data; don't filter the output from `sort -nr`.

The first `tr` only needs one slash, I think.  Normally, you'd map blanks and punctuation to newlines (with a `-s` option to `tr` to squeeze adjacent newlines to one).  The slashes from the first `tr` count as punctuation in the third `tr`, so it isn't obvious what you're up to there.  I think I'd expect to see something like:

```
cat "$@" |
tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '\n' |      # Convert any non-alpha character to newline
tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]' |   # Case-convert to lower case
sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

Note the use of `"$@"` rather than `$*`; there's no difference when the file names you specify don't contain blanks (newlines, tabs, etc); when they do, the `"$@"` form is correct and `$*` is not, so you may as well always use `"$@"`.  It is correct far more often than `$*` is.

For some C source code I had lying around, the output from the script was:

```
 246 n
 217 i
 153 int
 141 list
 124 if
 118 t
 103 char
  99 a
  97 size
  90 buffer
  89 context
  82 d
  81 void
  79 include
  79 h
  78 s
  65 for
  62 j
  55 ptr
  54 r
  54 const
  53 static
  53 sem
  51 pthread
  49 z
  49 oldneedle
  49 err
  47 to
  47 return
  46 mutex
  44 printf
  43 error
  43 c
```

Note that the word 'h' appears as often as the word 'include'; there's a reason for that!  The word `t` appears a lot, but that's because, for example, `size_t` is treated as two words by the filtering.  Preserving underscores is possible; change the first `tr` to use `'[:alpha:]_'` (note the underscore).  You eliminated digits, but you can keep those too if you want.

Comment: i tried this and i still get no output to terminal. i named the script wd and i run it using [ ./wd file.txt  ]where file.txt is the file inputed

Comment: Really?  Hmmm—that's surprising. No error messages—we'll need to debug it step by step, then. (It worked for me, of course; that's how I produced the sample output.) What I do in situations like this is `tmp=${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/wd.$$; cat "$@" | tee $tmp.1 | tr -cs '[:alpha:]' '\n' | tee $tmp.2 | ...`, adding a `tee $tmp.N` after each pipe that is worrying. Here, don't worry about the one after `cat`, nor add them around the `sort | uniq -c | sort -nr`; add one after each `tr` command. Run the script, and look at the first temporary file. If it is incorrect, we know what to fix.

Comment: are you putting this right into the terminal or is it a script?

Comment: I had a 4 line script, so that the `"$@"` would work with the names I specified: `sh -x x3.sh *.c` was what I invoked.  That primarily affects the `cat` command; the rest of the code depends on `cat` sending it information.  For debugging, you could simply type 3 lines of information at the terminal, and see what you get in the temporary files.  You might prefer to locate the temporary files in the current directory instead of `/tmp`; that's fine by me, too.

Comment: welp, im sorry, i spelled something wrong thats why it was being wierd.... Thank you so much for your help.